# Another kind of random graphs?

Tags: graph-theory, random-graphs

Maybe this is just another method to generate random graphs of a known kind, but it's not obvious for me, and I'd like to ask if someone sees this at a glance.

Start with an empty set of nodes. For $i = 1,\dots,n$ add a node $i$ and connect it to $k<n$ nodes picked uniformly at random from the set of previously added nodes (**with** replacement). By chance, nodes $1$ and $n$ may have degree 1 (and all the other nodes have degree 2), and node $1$ may have degree $n-1$, but thats unprobable.

Alternatives:

- Pick the $k$ nodes (to connect the new node $i$ with) **without** replacement. In this case, node $n$ will have degree $k$.
- Pick the $k$ nodes (to connect the new node $i$ with) only from the set $\{i-1,\dots,i-K\}$ with $K > k$.

Especially I'd like to know what the degree distribution will be. (And other distributions: clustering coefficient, betweenness, and so on.)

Comment: This is occasionally called "non-preferential attachment", but the name is a bit tongue-in-cheek; it's an allusion the Barabási–Albert "preferential attachment" model, which is much more well-studied. I don't know how many sources you'll find on non-preferential attachment, but there are some.

Comment: @MishaLavrov. Thanks for the name "non-preferential attachment". Indeed there are only a few sources - but there are some. In fact I found no thorough treatment.

Comment: In [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1908.03659.pdf) it is said, that Bollobás et al. showed in [this paper](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/rsa.1009) that "the graph in question has geometric degree distribution".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't comment, but I believe this is also known as the Uniform Attachment Model, or Uniform Attachment Graphs.
A study of Perfect Matchings and Hamilton cycles in such graphs, along with some more references and history can be found in this paper by Huseyin Acan:
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1908.03659.pdf

For the "sliding window model" you described, I also found the following reference:
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.08597.pdf
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UPA_model

Chapter 8 of this book
[https://www.win.tue.nl/~rhofstad/NotesRGCN.pdf](https://www.win.tue.nl/%7Erhofstad/NotesRGCN.pdf)
discusses a generalized preferential attachment model, of which the uniform attachment model is a limiting case for one of the parameters ($\delta \to \infty$).

Comment: Thanks a lot, dbal!

Comment: Another interesting paper is this: [On preferential and uniform attachment random
graphs](https://www.math-berlin.de/images/summerschool/randgraph-2017/Pachon-Presention%20BMS%20Berlin%202017.pdf)